# Dask and persistence of data on the cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, directed-acyclic-graphs, dask-distributed

I am working on a project that uses historical data and also incoming data for analysis.  I would like to learn how to manage updating incoming data on dask while not having to dispatch all the historical data every time.

I gather data for time series for analysis, but the time series grow with incoming data, and the incoming data for each stream needs to be sent to the appropriate worker for things like ARMA analysis.  If I do ARMA analysis for weather, I would want to keep barometric pressure separate from temperature and perform analysis by comparing pressure to pressure and temperature to temperature.  I don't want to append the new temperature data to the prior temperature data and the dispatch the now larger series to a new worker.  I would like to send only the new temperature data to the dask worker that already had all the prior temperature data, and so on.  How can I ensure the prior temperature data persists on the worker, and how do I dispatch (only) the new temperature data to the worker that has the prior data.

I have done some basic things with dask, but all the basic lessons don't address persistence of the *history* and *methods* on the worker-only persistence of the results.

In addition this data is not based in Dask series or dataframes, but in classes that hold different data and methods related to the analysis method.  So I cannot effectively use a dask series or dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: rather than a metaphor, a more concrete example would be helpful. what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I updated the explanation to be closer to the exact question rather than the metaphor.

Comment: this is a relatively uncommon use case for dask, but it's certainly possible. just to be clear - your idea here is to run the dask job forever, with workers which maintain data in memory and wait to respond to requests? generally, I'd recommend that you use pure, or at least eventually-consistent functions to increase reliability. But you could set up such a model if you'd like. One thing to check out would be [dask.distributed Actors](//distributed.dask.org/en/stable/actors.html), which allow a stateful and object-oriented workflow. I would definitely read the section on limitations, though.

Comment: generally, it's tough to concretely answer this question without more detail. If you want an example implementation, a [mre] in pure python that we could help move to dask would be a helpful starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the right solution, but one possibility is to designate specific workers to perform specific computations. For example, let's separate the workers into two groups:

```py
# instantiate workers
from distributed import Client
c = Client(n_workers=5)

# here the separation is done based on order
# but custom logic can be implemented instead
workers_pressure = list(c.scheduler_info()['workers'])[3:]
workers_temperature = list(c.scheduler_info()['workers'])[:3]
```

Now, for tasks that are related to `pressure`, we can designate workers that are related to `pressure`:

```py
data_pressure = [4,5,6]
data_temperature = [1,2,3]

# scatter data to pressure/temperature workers
d_p = client.scatter(data_pressure, workers= workers_pressure)
d_t = client.scatter(data_temperature, workers=workers_temperature)

# submit computations to specific workers
function_pressure = lambda x: x**2
function_temperature = lambda x: x**2

f_p = client.map(function_pressure, d_p, workers=workers_pressure)
f_t = client.map(function_temperature, d_t, workers= workers_temperature)
```

In the above snippet, workers designated to handle pressure data will be used to run the pressure computations.

This won't scale well if you have a very heterogeneous set of tasks. If that is your situation, I'd first construct the task graph (DAG) and then let `dask` handle the most efficient assignment of workers to tasks.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I am wondering if we have to re-consider how we will do this data analysis or if we are overthinking the amount of time it will take to dispatch and receive the output.  This will definitely be our starting point if we hit issues.

Comment: Hmm, not sure, but by default dask scheduler does a pretty good job of allocating jobs to workers.

Comment: Also, if you are looking for stateful distributed processing, the actors as implemented in [dask](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/actors.html) or [ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/actors.html) might be relevant.

Comment: Thank you!  I have some thing that run now and appear to re-send the data to the workers where needed, but I hear (I am still learning the software) that the workers will swap tasks if the data is persisting on the cluster.  I am just trying to figure out how much of that will work out of the box and how much will need re-considering.